# Mvc using Jwt Bearer token authentication fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, jwt, middleware, asp.net-authorization

I'm working on a .NET core application.
What I want to accomplish is that some controllers need the user to be logged in, the authentication is done by a Jwt Bearer Token. Thus far I tried configuring my startup.cs with `app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication();` like this:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = "http://localhost:5122",
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:5122",
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                }
            });
```

Futher I decorated my controller with an `[Authorize]` attribute to make sure the user is logged in.
When I run without IIS I managed to catch the following 'error':

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed for user: (null).
```

Though I have no suggestion why the user is null because in the HttpContext it's just filled with the current users' claims. Could anyone provide me with some intel on where the problem lies or how to solve it? I can post specific code if nessecairy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hit to the post [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/06/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core](JWT In Asp Core), I wonder why Audience, Authority are not defined in your code, try to use simple options first.

Comment: The link you're reffering to isn't working

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/06/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/